# linux add another system admin

Tags: linux, system-administration, server-administration, user-administration

this is my first post in stackoverflow.

my questions:

1. i am root user in my linux system, i want to add another system admin and let him/her to help to do the admin job, what privilege should i design for that role(sysadmin).
2. what is the different between the root and admin in term of daily system usage.

background:

i am able to create a user call admin and add to root group. the admin is not able to do a lot of things especially restart httpd server and edit those conf file that owned by root.

i don't feel like give away root role in the system to others, but i want to give them another account so that they can do some admin works.

thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question would be better directed at SuperUser. StackOverflow is mainly focusing on programing-related issues.

Comment: hi chris, thank you thank you. you are the first one in stackoverflow to reply. thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useradd -o -u 0 -g 0 -M -d /root -s /bin/bash [username]

passwd [username]
```

that makes a copy of the root user, I really think you should set more limit to the new privileged user.

Answer (score 1):

root as a user can do basically everything with little intervention from OS -if any!
You could designate admin tasks like software management, user management, log reading - basically any command you can think to chosen users. To do this yopu would set up `sudo`. You can read more about `sudo` here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

By using `sudo` you can have regular users perform admin tasks from their own account - usually after providing their own password so root password is never disclosed. Alos, all sudo actions are logged for later audit.

You can as well add user to the special group `wheel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new user to sudo group (if you are using ubuntu)

`# usermod -aG sudo username`

if you are a redhat / centOS user , use the following command

`# usermod -aG wheel username`

when he wants to perform admin tasks, should use sudo in front of the command.

Example : Restart apache2

`$ sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Cheers